# X:code Spacing error anywhere?

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var QuestionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var Button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Button3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Button4: UIButton!


    var CorrectAnswer = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        RandomQuestions()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func RandomQuestions(){

        var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 4
        RandomNumber += 1

        switch(RandomNumber){
        case 1:

            QuestionLabel.text = "Who is the best soccer player in the world?"
            Button1.setTitle("Messi", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button2.setTitle("Neymar", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button3.setTitle("Bale", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button4.setTitle("James", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
             CorrectAnswer = "2"

            break
        case 2:
            QuestionLabel.text = "How many goals is a hat trick?"
            Button1.setTitle("2", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button2.setTitle("5", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button3.setTitle("3", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button4.setTitle("7", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "3"

            break
        case 3:
            QuestionLabel.text = "What number is Neymar?"
            Button1.setTitle("2", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button2.setTitle("5", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button3.setTitle("3", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button4.setTitle("11", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "4"
            break

        case 4:
            QuestionLabel.text = "What number is messi?"
            Button1.setTitle("2", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button2.setTitle("10", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button3.setTitle("3", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Button4.setTitle("7", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "2"



            break
        default:

            break
        }

    }

    @IBAction func Button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (CorrectAnswer == "1"){

            NSLog("You Are Correct")
        }
        else{
             NSLog("YOu Are Wrong")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func Button2Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (CorrectAnswer == "2"){

            NSLog("You Are Correct")
        }
        else{
            NSLog("YOu Are Wrong")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func Button3Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (CorrectAnswer == "3"){

            NSLog("You Are Correct")
        }
        else{
            NSLog("YOu Are Wrong")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func Button4Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (CorrectAnswer == "4"){

            NSLog("You Are Correct")
        }
        else{
        NSLog("You Are Correct")
        }
    }
```

Could anyone help me with this I'm need to coding and I need help with this. I have look for any extra brackets I put and I have seen none any help?

Comment: What is the issue ? Can you post exact error message or screenshot of error ?

Comment: @MidhunMP  http://prntscr.com/5zlnw5

Comment: In which line you are getting that error ?

Comment: @MidhunMP all the way at the end of the code there is a screen shot http://prntscr.com/5zlqxk

Comment: You are missing last `}` in your code (Closing bracket for your class notation)

Answer (score 1):

A useful feature for this sort of thing is to right-click somewhere in the file and select "Structure->Balance Delimiter" from the pop up menu. This will highlight all the code between the opening and closing delimiter. If a delimiter for that block of code is missing, it will beep at you.

In your case, you are missing the closing brace for the class definition itself.